# Using mod_pagespeed with Cloudfront and S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

We have a bunch of images that are loaded on Amazon S3. Right now we directly call these images with the S3 URL. I would like to install Cloudfront CDN and mod_pagespeed to resize these images and optimize them. The web server itself isn't hosted on Amazon at all.

How can I get Cloudfront to cache the mod_pagespeed's resized images? My idea was to spin up an EC2 instance and use it as a reverse proxy to S3. This EC2 instance would have mod_pagespeed installed. So it would go Cloudfront -> EC2 proxy -> S3. So far I haven't been able to get this to resize the images. It all works, just not the mod_pagespeed part.

We're not wanting the images to pulled to the web server out of Amazon as they would waste a lot of bandwidth. I want the images from S3 to be resized either on the new EC2 instance or some other way inside of Amazon.

Anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AWS Lambda - there are a number of examples of doing exactly what you're trying to do with it.